# Need to click 2 times to apply a class in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

I have list menu items, and I want to add a class on click and remove the same class for other element. How ever clicking for the first time does not effect. But clicking again on the same item will adding the class (and remove the class for existing item). What I am doing wrong here ?

Here is HTML

```html
<ul class="nav"> 
  <li><a class="active" ng-click="scrollTo($event,'glyphicons1')">Example</a></li> 
  <li><a class="" ng-click="scrollTo($event,'glyphicons2')">Alignment</a></li> 
  <li><a class="" ng-click="scrollTo($event,'glyphicons3')">Headers</a></li> 
  <li><a class="" ng-click="scrollTo($event,'glyphicons4')">Divider</a></li> 
  <li><a class="" ng-click="scrollTo($event,'glyphicons5')">Dinu items</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Here is the Script

```js
    $scope.scrollTo = function ($event, id) {
        if ($location.hash() !== id) {
            $scope.activeItem = id;
            $location.hash(id);
        } else {
            $anchorScroll();
        }
    };
```

The class I want to toggle is **active**.

I have the directive for the same purpose that also behaving in the same way.

Custom directive:

```js
myApp.directive('activate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.bind("click", function (e) {
                $("a").removeClass("active");
                element.addClass("active");
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**

I changed the **scrollTo()** function (Working perfectly) based on the answers. 
The change I need to do is to change the variable before calling **$location.hash()** function.

Comment: Just use `ng-class` for all of this. Stop using jQuery for things that angular can do for you as it is designed to do...using data model to drive the view

Comment: you miss the scope.$digest() or embed your code in scope.$apply

Comment: Also makes no sense using `$.when` for things that don't return a promise. If you do use promises...use built in `$q` not jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As adeel_s mentioned, use ng-class.

Check [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CqIsHlx4jY5vVzJvOYgy?p=preview)

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav"> 
  <li><a class="active" ng-class="{'active' : activeItem==='glyphicons1'}" ng-click="scrollTo($event,'glyphicons1')">Example</a></li> 
  <li><a class=""  ng-class="{'active' : activeItem==='glyphicons2'}"  ng-click="scrollTo($event,'glyphicons2')">Alignment</a></li> 
  <li><a class="" ng-class="{'active' : activeItem==='glyphicons3'}" ng-click="scrollTo($event,'glyphicons3')">Headers</a></li> 
  <li><a class="" ng-class="{'active' : activeItem==='glyphicons4'}" ng-click="scrollTo($event,'glyphicons4')">Divider</a></li> 
  <li><a class="" ng-class="{'active' : activeItem==='glyphicons5'}" ng-click="scrollTo($event,'glyphicons5')">Dinu items</a></li> 
</ul>
```

**Script:**

```
    $scope.activeItem='glyphicons1';
   $scope.scrollTo = function ($event, id) {
        $scope.activeItem=id;

    };
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you making it so difficult when you can just use angular built in `ng-class` directive?

you can use it something like

```
ng-class="{'active' : expression"}
```

Read more about ng-class [**here**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I used this method too. Still I need to click twice to apply the class. I believe  "$location.hash(id);" giving the trouble. Please check the edit.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help I got the solution. I updated the question.